# Vite + Vue 2.7 + Vue router - does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vite

I am trying to run an application with the following specs
Vue (v2.7) + Vite (v3.1.0) + vitejs/plugin-vue2 and vue-router(v3.6.5).

Facing the following error on

> The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=4ee861bd' does not provide an export named 'default'

Following is my `vite.config.js`

```js
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue2";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    minify: isProd
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["vue-router"]
  },
  plugins: [vue()]
});
```

Even with the *optimizeDeps* included I am seeing the export named default issue. What changes do I need to make in the `vite.config.js`?

Comment: Use the previous version (3.x.x) of Vue Router.

Comment: I have no such pb with vite@3.1.3, @vitejs/plugin-vue2@1.1.2, vue@2.7.10 and vue-router@3.6.5 but I didn't have an "optimizeDeps" entry on my config. Can you share a minimal reproductible example ?